# Regex: Match the last 4 words from any sentence/lines

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

good day. I want to match/select the last 4 words from any sentence from my notepad++.

I try this regex, but is not too good...Can anyone help me?

Search: `[^x](x*)(\w+\w*){4}$`

Comment: What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else? And, similarly, what is a sentence?

Comment: alphabetics, like "house, man, love, me, book, car, verbs, substantives,. etc", with or without dots :) And without numbers. Just words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?:[^a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+){3}[^a-zA-Z]*$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/yoj0W6/2)

---

To answer your question in comment:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `([^a-z]+[a-z]+)([^a-z]+[a-z]+)([^a-z]+[a-z]+)([^a-z]+[a-z]+)(?=[^a-z]*)$`
- Replace with: `$2$4$3$1`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/vilyim/1)

**Explanation:**

```
([^a-z]+[a-z]+)     # group 1, 1 or more non letters followed by 1 or more letters
([^a-z]+[a-z]+)     # group 2, 1 or more non letters followed by 1 or more letters
([^a-z]+[a-z]+)     # group 3, 1 or more non letters followed by 1 or more letters
([^a-z]+[a-z]+)     # group 4, 1 or more non letters followed by 1 or more letters
(?=[^a-z]*)         # positive lookahead, optional non letters (i.e. punctuation)
$                   # end of line
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

---

For the 4 first words:

- Find what: `^[^a-z]*([a-z]+[^a-z]+)([a-z]+[^a-z]+)([a-z]+[^a-z]+)([a-z]+[^a-z]+)`
- Replace with: `$2$4$3$1`

Comment: thank you very much !!

Comment: and Toto, if I am here. How can I inverse the first 4 words in the line? Maybe you can Edit your solution with this answer, too. :)

Comment: @JustMe: see my edit.

Comment: I would have liked it to be that simple, just put `^` at the begining of your formula. But it does not working this trick. I've tried it before ask you :)

Comment: @JustMe: It's not just `^` at the beginning, reread carefully the new regex. I've missed a closing parenthesis at the end, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will do it:
[(?:\S*\s*){4}$](https://regex101.com/r/bmy4pi/1)

The above Online regex tester link contains the full explanation of the elements
composing the expression.